# Extjs Model Fields with Subfields

Tags: extjs, model, grid, field

Anyone know how you model subfields of any field in ExtJS? For example

Ext.data.Model:

```
fields:[
   {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
   {name: 'title', type: 'string'},
   {name: 'description', type: 'string'},
   {name: 'priority', type: 'auto', fields:[
      {name: 'code', type: 'string'}
   ]},
   {name: 'createdBy', type: 'auto'},
]
```

then in my grid panel

Ext.grid.Panel

```
columns:[
    {header:'Title', dataIndex:'title', flex:1},
    {header:'Priority', dataIndex:'code'}
],
```

Any idea how I access the dataIndex 'code' under 'priority'? thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you can see my example to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694550/1496088

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @sha - here is the answer I needed :)

Model

```
fields:[

            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'title', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'description', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'priority', type: 'auto'},
            {name: 'code', type: 'string', mapping:'priority.code'},
            {name: 'createdBy', type: 'auto'},

        ]
```

Gird Panel

```
columns:[

             {header:'Title', dataIndex:'title', flex:1},
             {header:'Description', dataIndex:'description'},
             {header:'Priority', dataIndex:'code'}

         ],
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
dataIndex: 'priority.code'
```

Comment: can you use `mapping` feature of the Model to get scalar field from the nested information from your JSON/XML data source?

Comment: thanks for that... mapping is key once again... poorly documented :)

Comment: this works also but just for records are not null. if priority is null, it try to get code field of null and it causes error.

Comment: @sha: it runs as I say it above, for my store, I used `mapping: 'relatedProductType.id'` to get rid off null exception. however, it still gives me `Cannot read property 'id' of null`. have you got any idea?